# passing a structure into a function creates a sefault error

Tags: c, function, struct, segmentation-fault

both of these functions are (under my compiler at least) guaranteed to create a seg fault, yet i have no idea why. i really like their functionality and i have seen similar examples, so i am curious to know what is going wrong here or how to do what i think this actually does, which is passing a "level" into some function and then being able to manipulate its variable (eg lvl.lvl_cl[x][y][z] = some_number) and then pass it back for further use

any help is appreciated :)

```
typedef struct {
    int lvl_cl[500][500][50];
    char lvl_ch[500][500][50];
} level;

level plugh(level * in_lvl){
    in_lvl->lvl_cl[444][444][44]++; //it segfaults even if this line is removed
    return * in_lvl;
}

level foo(level inlvl){
    inlvl.lvl_cl[443][443][43]++;   //it segfaults even if this line is removed
    return inlvl;
}

int main(void){
    level world;
    plugh(&world);
    foo(world);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: 12.000 KO worth of int. Wow! Read your comment. Use something like this: define the `level` as `*level` and create the object on the heap using the `new` keyword. It will help you most certainly.

Comment: Do you know that your struct is not initialized?

Comment: @AdrianMar This is a C question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `foo` function it copies the whole `world` structure and it is quite big. Try to pass the pointer:

```
void foo(level *inlvl){
    inlvl->lvl_cl[443][443][43]++;
}
```

Comment: Well, it's so much more than this. C doesn't have references. Even if they did, there is a stack allocated instance of the struct.

Comment: would the not being able to pass by reference be the reason it keeps saying "...: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token" when i try to compile the above code

Comment: @Jacob: I'm sorry `C` doesn't have references. Try to use pointers, I've updated my post.

Comment: @Jacob Passing it in as a pointer won't help unless you also allocate it on the heap. Elalfer didn't say this and didn't take the hint from my comment.

Comment: thanks guys! after passing it as a pointer and allocating it to the heap, it is working! thanks (for future reference in case anyone stumbles on this here is the final code that works for me `#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
 int lvl_cl[500][500][50];
 char lvl_ch[500][500][50];
} level;

void foo(level * inlvl){
 inlvl->lvl_cl[443][443][43]++;
}

int main(void){
 
level *world;
 world = (level*) malloc (sizeof (level));
 foo(world);
 return 0;
 }
`

Comment: Please don't typecast the return from malloc.

Answer (score 3):

Stack overflow?

Seriously, have you ever considered how big your struct is? If you store it on the stack it will overflow...

Try a `sizeof(level)`, it would be interesting to see the actual size.

**EDIT:** If you need something that big, you really should consider where and how you store it. If you pass it to a function, you will make a *copy* of the structure and place it on the stack. If you return the struct you will most likely need another copy of the stack.

Do you really need to pass and return the struct? If not, you could place it in normal static memory (a plain *global variable*) or allocation one on the heap. Either way, if you pass around a pointer to it, it would only consume a fraction of the full structure.

Comment: half my problem is that i need it that big... this is actually down from world [10][1000][1000][1000][100][10] lol

Comment: trust me, you do NOT need it that big. and you need to allocate it using malloc so it goes on the heap rather than the stack.

Comment: Are you *sure* you need a data structure that big? You do realize that `int world [10][1000][1000][1000][100][10]` has *ten trillion* elements, right?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that's a LOT of memory:

500x500x50x1 (because 1 byte in char) +
500x500x50x4 (because 4 bytes in an int) =
59.605MB of memory.

You are storing this all on the stack, rather than using pointers and allocating it on the heap, which should cause a stack overflow.

Furthermore, in your plugh and foo functions, you are returning a whole new struct. Why pass by pointer, modify the object, and then return a copy? Every time you call these functions you are allocating another 59.605MB of memory because you are returning a copy. However, since you aren't using the copy, the compiler is probably optimizing and removing this expensive copy.

Comment: Well it's even more than that because of alignment, best part of 100MB!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are putting around 100MB on the stack and your stack isn't that big.

You need to start using pointers to this `level` struct and heap allocation rather than trying to copy it onto the stack!

Answer (score 1):

It segfaults

```
0x8048471 <main>:       lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
0x8048475 <main+4>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x8048478 <main+7>:     pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
0x804847b <main+10>:    push   %ebp
0x804847c <main+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x804847e <main+13>:    push   %esi
0x804847f <main+14>:    push   %ebx
0x8048480 <main+15>:    push   %ecx
0x8048481 <main+16>:    sub    $0xb2d060c,%esp
0x8048487 <main+22>:    lea    -0x7735958(%ebp),%eax
0x804848d <main+28>:    lea    -0x3b9acb8(%ebp),%edx
0x8048493 <main+34>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)      <<---- segfaults here
0x8048497 <main+38>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x804849a <main+41>:    call   0x80483f4 <plugh>
```

The fault occurs when addressing the new stack pointer after allocating a stack frame of 62,500,000 bytes (32 bit `int`).

Large structures should always be passed by reference.  Especially considering the logic of `foo()`.

Comment: Not just passed by reference, but heap allocated. Look for the stack allocated local variable in main.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a function that just passes a ref to your structure and returns nothing?
Something along the lines void foo(level* var){// your code here that modifies var}
And in main you just call foo(&myVar).

Passing such a huge structure as a parameter to a function or having it as a return value might create a bit of trouble for you. Also if you really need to have a return value try also returning a reference to your struct. 
 like level* foo(level* in){ //your code here }.

And in main you just dereference the function result like level myLvl= *(foo(&myOtherLvl)). That way all you pass in your function are refs to your structs, witch are basically integers. Hope this helps